# How to store the value of a global variable in an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I have a game that I would like to save the high score for.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
  /* high score stuff */
  var score = 0;
  var highscore = 0;
  var scoreelement = $('#highscoredisplay');

  //showing high score
  function calchighscore(){
    highscore = $.get('highscore');
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.html',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#highscoredisplay')
        }

    //set score to wincount
    score = wincount;  
    if(score > highscore){
        highscore = score;
    }
    showscore();
  }
```

My ajax call doesn't work and it's because I don't know how to make the appropriate call.  Right now I am able to increase my high score with the increase in wins however the high score isn't saved after exiting the game.

Can anyone help me out?  I think I need to use get on my highscoredisplay but I don't know how.  I have been searching many examples but I can't find quite what I'm looking for or maybe I just don't understand what I'm looking for...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PageMethod to get the score like this:

```
function calchighscore() {
    PageMethods.GetHighScore($.get('highscore'), OnSuccess, OnFailure);
    function OnSuccess(data) {
      score = wincount;
      if (score > data) {
          highscore = score;
      }
    function OnFailure() {
        alert('failed');
    }  
}
```